# How to change static class logic cuasing object refrence not to set an isnstance of object issue?

Tags: c#, static

I have a problem using quee class and static refrences.

Here is my code :

```
protected static Queue reportQueue = new Queue();

protected static ReportDocument CreateReport(Type reportClass)
{
    object report = Activator.CreateInstance(reportClass);
    reportQueue.Enqueue(report);
    return (ReportDocument)report;
}

public static ReportDocument GetReport(Type reportClass)
{
    int maxPrintLimit = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxPrintLimit"].ToString());
    //75 is my print job limit.
    if (reportQueue.Count > maxPrintLimit) ((ReportDocument)reportQueue.Dequeue()).Dispose();
    return CreateReport(reportClass);
}
```

I know that static and multiple threads cuasing issues.

So for example, If there is a static method and inside it there is a static field. In multile threads, If one thread change the property value, another thread might use the same proprty. at that time an object out of refrence object might happen if the first thred set it to null.

Will my code experince this issue since I am getting object refrence not to set to an instance of object running this code.

and How can I solve that ?

Will removing static make it work ?

Any suggestions is helpfull.

Thanks

Comment: If you do anything concurrently you have to make sure it will not cause issues. Static or non-static doesn’t make a difference. You need to use concurrent data structures or locking.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Thanks, so This is earlier developer code, I thinks he was trying to use a factory pattern but in a wrong way I will change the code and check Thanks.

Comment: Use `ConcurrentQueue`.

Comment: `I am getting object refrence not to set to an instance of object` Which line is throwing that exception?

Comment: The Exception logger is not identifying the error line.

Comment: You might want to use `ConcurrentQueue` class here as it is thread safe

Comment: @mjwills Hi,  Can you provide a sample code please ? if it is possible

Comment: `The Exception logger is not identifying the error line.` You should change your logger to include the Stack Trace to identify the cause.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks I wil. Actually I am new to this project just one week so far I am fixing issues one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my code to this :

```
protected static ConcurrentQueue<object> reportQueue = ConcurrentQueue<object();

    protected static ReportDocument CreateReport(Type reportClass)
    {
        object report = Activator.CreateInstance(reportClass);
        reportQueue.Enqueue(report);
        return (ReportDocument)report;
    }

    public static ReportDocument GetReport(Type reportClass)
    {
        int maxPrintLimit = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaxPrintLimit"].ToString());
        //75 is my print job limit.
        if (reportQueue.Count > maxPrintLimit)
        {
             object obj;
             if (reportQueue.TryDequeue(out obj))
             {
                 ((ReportDocument)obj).Dispose();
             }
        }
        return CreateReport(reportClass);
    }
```

Comment: That will be thread safe. Note that the use of `Count` will be slower than in a `Queue`. Also comparing the `Count` vs `maxPrintLimit` has a race condition where if multiple threads hit that check at the same time (and the queue has 26 items in it) they will both `TryDequeue` and thus go down to 74 items (not 75). Plus you likely want to use `ConcurrentQueue<ReportDocument>` instead of `ConcurrentQueue<object>`. Also consider instead using `BlockingCollection` with `BoundedCapacity` set - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/blockingcollection-overview .

Comment: @mjwills. Thanks for your answer, I will take that consideration into action later but for now let me fix the issue, becuase my end users can not print the report at this moment. I made it object becuase I  have this method CreateInstance which return object  other wise if I use report document then no need to have the Activator.CreateInstance(reportClass);

Comment: `I made it object becuase I want to make it generic` If you are only storing `ReportDocument` in it, that is ill advised.